# Erlang Config File Oddness

Tags: configuration, erlang, configuration-files, erlang-shell

I have got the following .erlang file in my home directory (Ubuntu):

```
io:format("executing user profile in home/user/.erlang\n",[]).
code:add_pathz("/media/user/Disk2/Cloud/Workspace/Erlang").
code:add_pathz("/media/user/Disk2/Cloud/Workspace/Erlang/code").
shell_default:cd("/media/user/Disk2/Cloud/Workspace/Erlang").
io:format(".erlang rc finished\n",[]).
```

I can see that the file is run when I start the Erlang shell in the terminal. What is more, the shell_default:cd-command works fine. However, the code:add_pathz-commands do not. When I try to run anything in the code-directory, I get an "undefined function"-error. Besides, when I list the paths with "code:get_path().", I get:

```
[".","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-2.16.4/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-1.19.4/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/xmerl-1.3.5/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/wx-1.1.1",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/webtool-0.8.9.2/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/typer-0.9.5/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/tv-2.1.4.10/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/tools-2.6.13/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/toolbar-1.4.2.3/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/test_server-3.6.4/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/syntax_tools-1.6.12/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/ssl-5.3.2/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/ssh-3.0/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/snmp-4.25/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-2.3.4/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/runtime_tools-1.8.13/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/reltool-0.6.4.1/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/public_key-0.21/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/pman-2.7.1.4/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/percept-0.8.8.2/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.0.10/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/otp_mibs-1.0.8/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/os_mon-2.2.14/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/orber-3.6.26.1/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/odbc-2.10.18/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/observer-1.3.1.2/ebin",
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/mnesia-4.11/ebin",
[...]|...]
```

Why isn't "code:add_pathz" working? Thanks.

Erlang R16B03
Eshell V5.10.4
Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Comment: Try running `rp(code:get_path()).` instead, as that will show the entire path rather than abbreviating it. The paths you added will be at the end.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Using the rp-command shows that the directories listed in the .erlang-file have been added to the path.

Answer (score 0):

The path above works. The fault was with .beam-files in the code-directory. Recompiling made them accessible from outside the "code"-directory.